# Terminal services and screen savers

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services, windows-mobile

I have a Window Server 2008 R2 server acting as a terminal server for mobile devices running a single application, but I am having issues with the screen saver popping on after ten minutes.  Is there a setting in terminal services to make the screensaver settings universal?  If not, how should I approach this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this via group policy:

User Configuration, Administrative templates, Control Panel, Display
Check out Screen Saver, Screen saver executable name, and Screen saver timeout